# check an array of characters only contains digits/numbers

Tags: c#, .net

I'm a newbie in c# and i want to figure out how to check if a char array values are entirely composed of number/numeric/digits

I tried this code :

```
 bool t=true;
 for (int k = 0; k < chain.Length; k++)
 {
    if(!(Convert.ToInt32(chain[k]) in {"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"}))
      {t=false ; }
          }
```

The syntax is not correct, and I want to know if there is an easy way to do this check without using t-sql.

Comment: Not sure why you mentioned t-sql, if the char array is on the local machine (.Net Application), the value is not longer in the Sql Server.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use LINQ [`.All`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548541.aspx) and [`char.IsDigit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f0ddtxh.aspx):

```
var isNumeric = chain.All(char.IsDigit);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're new, here's a more... classic way :

```
bool t = true;
foreach (char ch in word)
{
    if (!char.IsDigit(ch))
    {
         t = false;
         break;
    }
}
```

Comment: An improvement: code like this should always use `break` to stop the iteration as soon as the final result is known.

Comment: Yes, you are very right. First, I wrote it as a method not a sequence of code that had returned a bool, and then I thought of trying to match manu's code, so I forgot of the break. I have updated it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private bool ValuesAreNumeric(object[] values)
{
    foreach (var value in values)
    {
        var stringValue = Convert.ToString(value);
        double number;
        if (!double.TryParse(stringValue, out number)) return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```